# Java error incompatible types InputStream cannot be converted to Serializable

Tags: serializable

While using invoke method in oaf to call a method from AM i have an input stream variable to pass while using serializable to pass the parameters  i'm facing an java error incompatible types saying input stream cannot be converted into serializable.Is there any other method to pass the values .Please help.Thanks.

```
 try {  
     DataObject fileUploadData = pageContext.getNamedDataObject("Upload");
       if (fileUploadData != null) {
           String FileName = (String)fileUploadData.selectValue(null, "UPLOAD_FILE_NAME");
           String contentType = (String)fileUploadData.selectValue(null, "UPLOAD_FILE_MIME_TYPE");
           BlobDomain uploadedByteStream = (BlobDomain)fileUploadData.selectValue(null, FileName);
       BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api=(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection)oam.invokeMethod("adminClient");

           **Serializable parameters[]={entityName,key, FileName,uploadedByteStream.getInputStream(),api};**    // Incompatible type error found for the last two values.Expecting serializable but found Input stream and api.
           BoxFile.Info file = (BoxFile.Info)oam.invokeMethod("UploadFile",parameters);
           return file;
        } else {
             pageContext.putDialogMessage(new OAException("Please choose the file",  OAException.ERROR));
          }
  }
```

Comment: Provide your code for reference

Comment: Hi  user7294900, i have posted the code.Thanks.